# Azure.RequestFailedException-This request is not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, blob

I created an blob trigger azure function with private end point(Virtual network-test36002ram1, sunbet:snet-ram-01). And created a storage account with private end point in the same virtual network and with sub net as above. I added the function app service principal for storage account contributor role  as well. Somehow I'm getting the below error. Am I missing something here?

**Error:**
This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:e517fe4f-c01e-0070-07b4-a43ee9000000
Time:2023-06-22T02:53:38.9206879Z
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure

Content:

`AuthorizationFailure`This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

RequestId:e517fe4f-c01e-0070-07b4-a43ee9000000
Time:2023-06-22T02:53:38.9206879Z

Headers:
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: e517fe4f-c01e-0070-07b4-a43ee9000000
x-ms-client-request-id: dbe8fd96-7653-46d7-89c4-398fe7a4d5a3
x-ms-error-code: AuthorizationFailure
Date: Thu, 22 Jun 2023 02:53:38 GMT
Content-Length: 246
Content-Type: application/xml
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Azure.RequestFailedException-This request is not authorized to perform this operation

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

I have integrated vnet with function app and then created a storage account with private endpoint and it worked as below:

[image]

and when i added ports to block the access, then i faced 403 access error :

[image]

Blob trigger Output:

[image]

After removing the rules which are unecessary got the succeded results as below:

[image]

I havent added any firewall.
Try to check your permissions clearly, as i am getting output.